# Azure Resource Manager Service connection using automated security: What permissions are assigned over the Resource Group?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security) when you create an Azure Resource Manager service connection to a certain Resource Group, *Azure DevOps connects with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) and creates an app registration with a secret that's valid for two years*.

Well, what exactly are the permissions given to this app registration over the Resource Group? Same than the account which is creating the service connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a automated Azure Resource Manager Service connection in Azure Devops, it will automaticlly create a service principal in Azure Active Directory(Named: `Orgname-projectname-SubscriptionID`).

You could navigate to `Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations`.

[image]

When using this automatic service connection in azure devops, azure sources are operated through this service principal instead of the account which is creating the service connection.

This service principal has the [Contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) in Azure Resource Group.

> Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC, manage assignments in Azure Blueprints, or share image galleries.

[image]

You can search for the service principal name in `Resource Group -> Access control` to check its permissions

Comment: Great and complete answer. I would like to allow deployments but block the creation of new resources within the RG (contributor role allows this) when using service connection. I understand that there is no task available which could be used by pipeline creators to create new resources in the RG. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean that create resources in Azure Resource Group with Azure Pipeline? If yes, the ARM template deployment task could do it if you have the ARM template.

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I mean. Any way of blocking that using a service connection with automated security? Is the creation of a service principal (with restricted permissions) for creating the service connection the only way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> what exactly are the permissions given to this app registration over the Resource Group?

It is a [`Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) role, also did a quick test for you.

[image]

[image]

> Same than the account which is creating the service connection?

No, the account needs to be the `Owner` of the subscription, otherwise it will not have the permission to assign the role to the AD App i.e. service principal.